# Text added instead of being set in .NET TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

This is my `LostFocus` event handler:

```
    private void txtThrow_LostFocus(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox source = (TextBox)sender;

        if (source.Text == "")
            source.Text = "0";
    }
```

This actually interferes with `txtThrow_KeyPress`, so that after I do my processing on my `TextBox` which accepts to only hold one character, I find it having two: mine and this zero you see here!! What I want to do is to keep `txtThrow_KeyPress` exactly as it is, but whenever the user types nothing, I want to enforce a zero.

What I can understand from here is that `txtThrow_LostFocus` is triggered before `txtThrow_KeyPress` is done with its job, since at the time `txtThrow_LostFocus` is triggered, the text is still empty. How can that be correct?!

Comment: What processing are you doing in the KeyPress event ?

Comment: Why is this relevant? I just keep some characters (and take some actions) and prevent others from showing.

Comment: Because what you are doing is affecting your `LostFocus` event, that event is fired after the `KeyPress` event. You may want to try the `Leave` Event, that gets fired when the Textbox is no longer the Active Control. And if you show us what you are doing in the `KeyPress` event it will help us duplicate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the TextChanged event instead of the KeyPress event.  I am assuming the text box could be empty already, and the user presses Backspace or something of the nature.

TextChanged event is triggered every time the text is changed within the field.

And the code you have should work perfectly fine when you fill the new event handler method with such.  However, you may need to use

```
private void txtThrow_LostFocus_TextChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

    TextBox source = (TextBox)sender;

    if (source.Text == "" || source.Text == null)
        source.Text = "0"
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try to this code
private void txtThrow_LostFocus_TextChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

```
TextBox source = (TextBox)sender;

if (string.nullorempty(source.text)
    source.Text = "0"
```

}